# Analyzing variable length

Tags: php, coding-style

Is there a code analyzing utility that can do things like calculate the average variable length in a script or in a bunch of scripts? I'm obsessed with the linguistic aspect of programming. I'd be curious to see how different frameworks or CMSs compare in that aspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a code analyzing utility that
>   can do things like calculating the
>   average variable length in a script or
>   a bunch of scripts? I'd be curious to
>   see how different frameworks or CMSs
>   compare in that aspect.

Your question isn't clear but probably you are looking for a profiler, have a look at:

- [PHP Quick Profiler](http://particletree.com/features/php-quick-profiler/)

[image]

> I'm just obsessed with naming
>   conventions and the linguistic aspect
>   of programming.

You need to have a look at [PHP Coding Standards](http://www.dagbladet.no/development/phpcodingstandard/) actually.